# Get code from REPL

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

If I'm entering code into the REPL using `clisp`, as in the program you get when you do `sudo apt-get install clisp`, is there a way to take all the code you've entered so far and save it in a file? I'm a Lisp beginner so I don't know if that's a ridiculous request or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start output recording with the function [DRIBBLE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_dribbl.htm).

Other than that I would run CLISP from a terminal program which can save input / output.

As the minimum I would usually use Emacs, run a shell via M-x shell and start the Lisp there. That way the I/O goes into an Emacs shell buffer.

There is also [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), which sets up quite a bit more functionality inside Emacs to communicate with a 'slave' Common Lisp. A 'listener' (aka REPL) is part of that.

Comment: A lot of what you said is Greek to me. Are you saying I can remotely connect to my Linux box if I use M-x shell? I want any files I create to end up on my Linux machine and it would be nice not to have to have to upload the files from my workstation to the Linux machine.

Comment: @Jason Swett: Run Emacs on your machine. M-x shell runs a shell inside emacs. Just a local shell. At the prompt start clisp. Done. Now all the I/O goes to the editor buffer for the shell. You can copy and paste text around with the usual editor commands.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way, but... If you are using a decent terminal program, you should be able to select the text in the terminal and save it to file. This would include your typed input as well as output, so you would have to manually remove the output.